# Move Chart series data via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code

```
Dim ss As Series
Dim strs() As String
Set ss = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
strs = Split(ss.Formula, ",")
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range(strs(2))
Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count + 1)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rg
```

This allows me to add 1 more item of data to my data series but I want it to also remove the 1st entry every time I run it. For example Day 1- range is A1 to C1 then I run the macro I want it to go to B1 to D1

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will "move" the range, rather than resizing it, which is what you're doing.

```
Set rg = rg.Offset(1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks @David Zemens for that but how can I get it to move the Category at the same time?

Comment: The series also has an `.XValues` property, which sets the categories.  Use that to assign the category labels. **Note:** this method is kind of clunky, you're assigning literal values rather than linking to the cells on the worksheet, so your chart will not "update" if the data changes.

Comment: Can I ask how you would suggest is the best method to do this?

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples of manipulating Excel charts all over the interweb. You might be able to use the `.SetSourceData` method ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196(v=office.14).aspx)).

Comment: Or you can assign a formula reference to the `.Values` and `.XValues` property (probably more reliable) like: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & rg.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address`

Comment: @DavidZemens - If you assign a range to .Values or .XValues, you are not assigning literal values, you are in fact assigning the range. You do however need to use a formula to assign a range to the .Name of a series. But use ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Address(External:=True) and let Excel figure out whether the sheet name requires single quotes etc.

Comment: @JonPeltier thanks for clarifying, my mistake (thinking about assigning variant arrays to those properties, which does the literal value)!

Comment: @DavidZemens - Sure. The Excel Charting Object Model is large and complicated and mostly unintuitive.