# Changing the Y-Values in Chart series Data

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add one more column to the data of my chart, just like in the question:
[Move Chart series data via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327258/move-chart-series-data-via-vba)
However, his code is changing the Y value of the chart and I can't find how to change the X-value

```
Dim ss As Series
Dim strs() As String
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
Set ss = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)
strs = Split(ss.Formula, ",")
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range(strs(1))
Set rg = rg.Resize(, rg.Columns.Count + 1)


ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = rg
```

The code I use now is changing the range of the Y axe, giving it the range of the X axe (putting it to the exact size of the Y range +1).
EDIT QUESTION: 
How can I change the value of the X axe?
How can I change the value of the Y axe?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you show us result of `Debug.Print ss.Formula` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jon Peltier's answer, I developed the following answer:

```
    Set ss = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)
    strs = Split(ss.Formula, ",")
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range(strs(1))
    Set rg = rg.Resize(, rg.Columns.Count + 1)
    Dim strx() As String
    strx = Split(strs(1), "!")

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Formula = strs(0) & "," & strx(0) & "!" & rg.Address & "," & strs(2) & "," & strs(3)
```

It seemed like the only way to change the X values

Answer (score 3):

The series formula looks like this:

```
=SERIES(Summary!$B$1,Summary!$A$2:$A$4,Summary!$B$2:$B$4,1)
```

so the elements of your array are:

strs(0): `=SERIES(Summary!$B$1` is mostly the series name,
strs(1): `Summary!$A$2:$A$4` are the X values,
strs(2): `Summary!$B$2:$B$4` are the Y values,
strs(3): `1)` is the plot order and the closing paren.

define your rangelike this:

```
Set rg = Range(strs(2))
```

and not `strs(1)`, and you'll modify the Y values.

Comment: Actually, I had the issue the other way around. I wanted to change the value of the X axe and not Y ( I edited my question). The way you show is working to change the Y values but not the X values (it doesn t work with *Set rg = Range(strs(1))* )

Comment: What does your SERIES formula look like? Copy it and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

To change X-axis try as follows (it will move x-values to one column to the right):

```
Sub test()

Dim ss As Series
Dim strs() As String
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
Set ss = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)
strs = Split(ss.Formula, ",")
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range(strs(1))   ' X-values
Set rg = rg.Offset(0, 1)  ' moving one column to the right
rg.Select                 ' Selecting range for testing purposes

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = rg
'
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.